# Github Pages change content char set - utf8 and windows1256 Arabic

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, github-pages

I have an `html` page, [this address](https://marsii.github.io/T3st/1.html)

The `charset` of the above `html` file is `arabic`, (if you go to `view > text encoding > arabic(windows)` you can see correct page)

[image]

but by default, github server send `utf-8` charset:

```
$ curl -I https://marsii.github.io/T3st/1.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Last-Modified: Sat, 17 Dec 2016 03:55:24 GMT
```

and I can't change this `charset` with html code, I test this parameter:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
```

but my page does not show correctly and charset (in `view > textencoding`) is `utf-8` and not changed to Arabic.

How can I show my page correct with Arabic char-set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub Pages [expects pages to have been stored in UTF-8](https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-file-is-not-properly-utf-8-encoded/)

So [if you can encode your files in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2996528/6309) and push them back yo your GitHub repo, GitHub pages will serve them correctly.

Note that there were some recent GitHub pages changes
([markdown support, without Jekyyl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41071347/6309); [no more `gh-pages` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39033021/6309) if you want; [relative links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41127983/6309); [theme switcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41174937/6309))
So it is possible that some bugs do persist.

But using utf-8 files should be a good enough workaround, and will support any [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).

Comment: very thanks, i use his command in my linux and convert  html page ftom windows1256 to utf8 `iconv -f windows-1256 -t utf8 FILENAME -o FILENAME` ,thank you