# How do I turn a repository into a GitHub page?

Tags: git, github, web, migrate

I currently have a remote repository for serving a website and both back-end and front-end are hosted there.

The questions are:

- What is the best way for turning this repository into a GitHub page, abandoning the old back-end?
- Could this be done without dropping the current repo?

Note: The server just serves the html, css and js files.

Comment: AFAIK, its just naming the repo <username>.github.io and project root becomes the site root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the recent GitHub pages changes ([markdown support, without Jekyyl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41071347/6309); [no more `gh-pages` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39033021/6309) if you want; [relative links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41127983/6309); [theme switcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41174937/6309)), you should be able to convert a GitHub repo into a GitHub page one.

As commented, renaming your repo into `username.github.io` and configuring it to use the master branch should be enough to start seeing the content of your current repository in your own GitHub page.
But its content should be either markdown, or [with Jekyll metadata](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-as-a-static-site-generator-with-github-pages/), so some data changes are to be expected.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZkbu.png]